# Where exactly can BroadcastReceivers interrupt code?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, interrupt, race-condition

In a single-thread Android app, I [registerReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter))
to update some global variables when the screen turns off.

Every minute, however, a timer triggers the running of a block of code which I do not
want to be interrupted.  I know that there are "java.util.concurrent" tools to lock
execution to do exactly that, even if I were multi-threading, but I'd like to avoid
those complications if there are any Android guarantees about where my main looper
allows interruptions.

So, to help me understand the default behavior, does a registered receiver act ASAP
so that variables can get changed anywhere in the middle of my thread?

If so, I can easily put one or two "locking variables" in the code to reduce the risk
of problems, but taking that risk to 0% has a significant performance trade-off if
I deal with the race conditions inside my class.  So, instead I am planning to use an
[AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)
(which also of course has a trade-off, but potentially less since the Android OS can then schedule
interruptions in light of my given atomic requirements) for locking if I truly need 0% risk.
Or, is there a simpler solution for single-thread apps?

Comment: If by "timer" you mean `Timer`, then you do not have a single-thread app. This is why Stack Overflow asks for a [mcve], so we can better determine exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I'm using the Handler postDelayed method.

Comment: Your `run()` method will be run on the main application thread. Usually, if you registered the receiver normally, `onReceive()` will also be called on the main application thread. A thread cannot interrupt itself.

Comment: Everything is usual like you assume.  So, for example, code inside of onStartCommand
can never be interrupted by the onReceive code in a BroadcastReceiver?  That would
be great in my case, but is it guaranteed in some written Android/Java spec?  I was
thinking the Android OS (which could be considered another thread) might try to get
the onReceive code going ASAP and therefore effectively allow a thread to interrupt
itself...hoping for an actual answer if this is not the case.

Comment: "So, for example, code inside of onStartCommand can never be interrupted by the onReceive code in a BroadcastReceiver?" -- `onStartCommand()` of a `Service` is also called on the main application thread. "is it guaranteed in some written Android/Java spec?" -- this is Android. Nothing is guaranteed. However, I do not expect you to have problems. "the Android OS (which could be considered another thread)" -- um, no.

Comment: Thanks, that all sounds reasonable.  By the way, if I instead used two separate threads, the OS would arbitrarily start and stop them so that interruption of the onStartCommand (or interruption of a postDelayed run) could occur anywhere inside of its code, right?  In other words, an infinite loop within onStartCommand will not block onReceive code with separate threads, but would block it with a single thread, right?

Comment: "an infinite loop within onStartCommand will not block onReceive code with separate threads" -- you do not control what thread `onStartCommand()` runs on. That will always be the main application thread. I think there is some esoteric recipe to control the thread used for `onReceive()`, but typically this will also be called on the main application thread.